# Android/PHP - Encryption and Decryption

Tags: android, encryption

I'm struggeling with code from this page: http://www.androidsnippets.com/encrypt-decrypt-between-android-and-php

I want to send data from a server to an Android application and vice versa, but it should be sent as an encrypted string. However, I manage to encrypt and decrypt the string in PHP. But on Android the application crashes with the following error message when decrypting:
java.lang.Exception: [decrypt] unable to parse ' as integer.

This error occours here in the for-loop:

```
    public static byte[] hexToBytes(String str) {
        if (str==null) {
                return null;
        } else if (str.length() < 2) {
                return null;
        } else {
                int len = str.length() / 2;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[len];

                for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
                        buffer[i] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(str.substring(i*2,i*2+2),16);
                }
                System.out.println("Buffer: " + buffer);
                return buffer;
        }
}
```

This is by the way the string that should be decrypted: f46d86e65fe31ed46920b20255dd8ea6

Comment: if you want to have the latest version of the code you can get it here: https://github.com/SeRPRo/Android-PHP-Encrypt-Decrypt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're talking about encrypting and decrypting, but you're showing code which simply turns numeric bytes (such as `0x4F`) into strings (such as `"4F"`) -- which may be relevant to your transfer of data (if you cannot transfer binary format), but completely unrelated to encryption/decryption.

Since the Android code you have contains only a single Integer parse, have you examined the input you're giving it? `str.substring(i*2,i*2+2)` apparently contains data other than [0-9A-F] when the exception occurs. You should start by examining the string you've received and comparing it to what you sent, to make sure they agree and they only contain hexadecimal characters.

Edit -- passing the string "f46d86e65fe31ed46920b20255dd8ea6" through your hexToBytes() function works flawlessly. Your input is probably not what you think it is.

Comment: 03-15 19:56:36.882: I/System.out(6180): f46d86e65fe31ed46920b20255dd8ea6

Is the input value, so it turns out to be right :S

Comment: You already know the problem is with the parsing of the string, so have you sent str.substring(i*2,i*2+2) to your log so you could determine what pair is leading to the exception?

Comment: Double checked the input value, seems that it was wrong. The PHP page added four new lines before the actual encrypted string. However, when I encrypt the same string on Android it returns
Encrypted: �m��_��i �Uݎ�

Which is wrong according to the PHP-version since that returns f46d86e65fe31ed46920b20255dd8ea6

Comment: Problem was that I forgot to call the bytesToHex function after the encryption had been done.